# Exception thrown when calling Workbook.SaveAs() in Excel.Interop and C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, office-automation

We are experiencing a production issue whereby we call an Excel Workbook's `SaveAs` method with a password. The exception thrown is:

```
The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
```

The call is done as follows, where `_ExcelPassword` is the workbook's generated password and `ExcelOutputPath` is the location on disk the file should be written to:

```
workbook.SaveAs(ExcelOutputPath, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _ExcelPassword, _ExcelPassword, false, false);
```

There is no issue if the file is saved without a password though.

What am I missing please?

Comment: I switched a long time ago to this free library and never looked back ... it's great http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I ended up with was to save the workbook without a password, reopen it again, set the password on the workbook object and then save it again. Tedious, I know, but that completely fixed the `remote procedure call failed` issue I was getting